# Nodemailer: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, nodemailer

I have a problem using Nodemailer. These are the instructions I follow: http://www.nodemailer.com/docs/install

I'm using Grunt server.

**Step 1**
I start writing this command inside my project folder:
npm install nodemailer --save

And everything seems to be working, the nodemailer folder appears inside node_modules folder and inside package.json I have this line of code:

"dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "^0.6.3"
  },

**Step 2**
I try to reference to the nodemailer by writing this inside my javascript file:
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

**Error**
But then I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

**Other methods**
I have also tryed to do the following:
require("nodemailer.js");
require("/..path.../nodemailer.js");

But nothing seems to work.

Have anyone any idea why I can't access nodemailer? Please keep in mind that I'm new to javascript. Thank you :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `node -v` say?

Comment: What does your gruntfile look like?